# wordpress secure specific page with token

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, security

Hello I am trying to find a way to allow access to a specific wordpress page to website.

I have read that there are ways to use the htaccess to secure with IP or domain (referer) but that it is not the most secure or reliable.

So I have been looking for a way to use tokens? or any other method?

Thank you for your suggestions.

I am currently using password protect plugin and this plugin does have the option to secure a specific page and works great but I have not been able to set it where it protects: /securedpage and not /securedpage/?lkjsi293ndk:8sjhd

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a feature that allow you set up password at specific posts.

Open one of your post. You will see Publish segment at the top right menu.

[image: Visibility]

Click on Visility: Public **Edit** button. Change visibility to **Password Protected** from **Public** and set strong password.

[image]

When someone try to reach that post, wordpress going to ask password before show the content.

Comment: For some reason the theme I am using the password protection is not working but either way this doesn't help me, The visitors to this page are coming from a specific server where they had to log in already so what I was asked to do was to make this page available ONLY to people coming from that server and WITHOUT having to log in twice.